# How do I tell python to launch a users default terminal?

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I found this solution before, but it keeps trying to launch xterm instead of the default (in my case Terminator). Could someone help?

```
def terminal(self):
    if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        os.system('(cd .;$TERM; )'.format(self.dirname))
    elif sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        os.system('start /d {0} cmd'.format(os.path.normpath(self.dirname)))
```

Comment: running the script as sudo or something fishy?

Comment: TERM is the terminal capability, and has not much to do with the actual terminal program.

Comment: No its not being run as sudo, and what is the proper method then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TERM is the terminal capability, and has not much to do with the actual terminal program.

There's no standard for storing the default, it depends entirely on the distribution you use..

It could be

- in /etc/alternatives, probably `/etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator`
- with gnome, try `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal`

Note: haven't tried any of these...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the shell. In Xfce it is `exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator`. In GNOME it is `x-terminal-emulator`.